# Is a smooth cubic in $\mathbb P^2(\mathbb C)$ never birational to a line in $\mathbb P^2(\mathbb C)$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves, projective-space

Let $V$ be a smooth cubic in $\mathbb P^2(\mathbb C)$ ; then is it true that $V$ cannot be bi-rationally equivalent to $\mathbb P^1(\mathbb C)$ ?

We know that $V$ is bi-rationally equivalent to the cubic defined by

$Y^2Z=X^3+aX^2Z+bXZ^2+cZ^3$ . But I'm unable to say anything else (I'm not even sure whether this simplification of $V$ is helpful or not).

Please help. thanks in advance .

EDIT : Please don't use the concept of genus. I think it can be done without using genus.

Comment: A line has genus $0$ – a smooth cubic, genus $1$.

Comment: @Bernard: Please don't use the concept of genus

Comment: @users : in fact I might have another solution I'll write an answer.

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet: ok, thanks

Comment: Well, what *have* you learned, then? Do you know that every birational class of curves has a unique smooth projective representative? This reduces it to isomorphism invariance; which isomorphism invariants have you learned?

Comment: There are two proofs which boil down to field theory (hence do not use the concept of genus) in Reid's [*Undergraduate algebraic geometry*](https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/staff/Miles.Reid/MA4A5/UAG.pdf); see (2.2) and Exercise 2.12. Another proof is outlined in Hartshorne, Exercise I.6.2 for the particular cubic curve $y^2=x^3-x$, but as far as I can tell the same argument works for other cubics as well. The basic idea of Hartshorne's proof is that the coordinate ring of a(n affine) cubic curve is not a UFD, while (affine) rational curves have coordinate rings which are UFD's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f : X \to \Bbb P^1$ be a birational morphism. If $X$ is a smooth curve, you can show that $f$ should extend to a regular morphism.

Now, $f$ has degree $1$ so it should be an isomorphism, since it's injective and surjective.

This is a contradiction because a cubic curve is not isomorphic to $\Bbb P^1$ since even topologically they are different.

Comment: extend where to a regular morphism ? How do you prove it ?

Comment: So $f : X \to \Bbb P^1$ is birational means that there is a Zariski open $U$ and a morphism $f : U \to \Bbb P^1$. Now $U$ is $X$ minus some point, and take $p \in X \backslash U$. There are local coordinates $(z,w)$ around $p$ so that $f = [f_1(z,w):f_2(z,w)]$ where $f_1, f_2$ are homogenous polynomials of the same degree. Now, say $p$ corresponds to $(z_0,w_0)$ : you can do a Taylor expansion of $f_1,f_2$ at $(z_0,w_0)$ and see that necessarly you have either $0,\infty$ or a finite limit. In any case the morphism extends.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why $\mathbb P^1$ cannot be isomorphic with a cubic ?

Comment: A complex smooth projective cubic is homeomorphic to a torus $S^1 \times S^1$ and $\Bbb P^1$ is topologically $S^2$.